# How to Insert a Particular column in sql server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I Have Table of `Student` Attendence and having the columns like

```
st_id  |  StudentName  |   month  |  year  |  day1 to day30
```

And, asp.net i am using. when i click Present button the cols of database should insert the values of `st_id`, `StudentName`, `month`, `year`, and day should be `systemdate`. date should enter in day column in sql and remaining should be null values

```
suppose if i enter the date today ie, 4 data will enter in day4 col like present
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7LwU.png

Comment: This is the format. `Insert into tablename (columnname) values (value1)`

Comment: dynamic it should enter the current date in day col we should not modify again and again

Comment: i dont want to get date in column i want to insert present day column to present or absent like that i have to enter

Comment: @MeenaKonakondla I posted answer try that one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like this

```
DECLARE @st_id int=1
DECLARE @StudentName varchar(50)='dinesh'
DECLARE @month varchar(50)='jan'
DECLARE @year int=2014

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX)= 'insert into 
(st_id, StudentName, month, year,day'+CAST(datepart(day,GETDATE()) as 
varchar(10))+') values  
('+CAST(@st_id as VARCHAR(MAX))+','''+@StudentName+''','''+
CAST(@month as VARCHAR(MAX))
+''','+CAST(@year as VARCHAR(10))+',''present'')'
print @SQL
```

**Using Procedure**

```
Create procedure sp_insertStudents
@st_id int,
@StudentName varchar(50),
@month varchar(50),
@year int
as
BEGIN


DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX)= 'insert into 
(st_id, StudentName, month, year,day'+CAST(datepart(day,GETDATE()) as 
varchar(10))+') values  
('+CAST(@st_id as VARCHAR(MAX))+','''+@StudentName+''','''+
CAST(@month as VARCHAR(MAX))
+''','+CAST(@year as VARCHAR(10))+',''present'')'
print @SQL 
EXEC(@SQL)
END
```

**OUTPUT**

```
insert into (st_id, StudentName, month, year,day4) values  
(1,'dinesh','jan',2014,'present')
```

Comment: @MeenaKonakondla Now Updated

Comment: @ Ganesh_Devlekar Thanks for answer my question.how can create it in a storedprocedure

Comment: @ Ganesh_Devlekar output getting like this insert into (st_id, StudentName, month, year,day4) values  
(1,'cccc','11',2014,'present')  i dont want like this directly data values will enter in into table

Comment: as you said `insert the values of st_id, StudentName, month, year, and day should be systemdate. date should enter in day column in sql and remaining should be null values `

Comment: then what to do,that thing you do not mention in the question